# How to share the generated JMeter Report dashboard to stakeholders via email?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, test-report, performance-testing

Now that I have generated the report dashboard after the JMeter test run, I want to share the same via email to concerned members and stakeholders. Please suggest how can I do the aforementioned task!

Answer (score 3):

- If are asking [how to send a file via email](https://lifehacker.com/5803366/how-to-send-an-email-with-an-attachment-for-beginners) then I'm not sure the "stakeholders" will need this report as if a person is not capable of accomplishing this simple activity I strongly doubt the load report is relevant
- If you need to do it using JMeter - you can pack the folder with the dashboard report using [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) and [SMTP Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) (it will be a separate JMeter test of course)
- If you are running your test using a [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) solution check out your CI server plugins, for instance there is [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin for [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Many thanks for your time!
Post running the test I have the report dashboard saved in a folder somewhere on my system (maybe on Desktop). Now that folder has an index.html file opening which I can view the results of my test. How do I share the same over the email to others?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is less value to share file created by automation or performance tool with stakeholders. They will not understand it. What I would suggest you is to create a short presentation (7-15 min) to present the results and answer the possible questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion if you like you can place the folder in a webserver like IIS and host a site, and send the link to the stakeholders, that ways you have to update the result set with every run, and you can do the automation around it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy .csv file for same test within the same folder and make it zip and can share that zip file with anyone :)